# Is an external keyboard with the keys from the new Macbook available for purchase?

Tags: keyboard

Is an external keyboard with the keys from the new Macbook available for purchase? I'd like to get the San Fransisco font key caps and crisp new mechanics in an external keyboard.

Apple describes the keyboard on their site...

> Now when your finger strikes the key, it goes down and bounces back with a crisp, consistent motion that makes typing with precision a breeze.

It definitely feels good to type on and I'd love to acquire those mechanics in the size of the [Apple Keyboard with Numeric Keypad](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB110LL/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-us-english?fnode=56).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only apple can answer it

Comment: Reduce the question to simply "is one available" & it becomes answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, no, it is not possible to buy one.

I must admit that I would like one too, especially if it also has a Magic Touch Bar.